# Pattern.quote not working as expected

Tags: java, regex

I wrote a unit test to help me understand Pattern.quote and for the life of me can't figure out why this test isn't passing.

```
@Test
public void testRegexEscape() throws Exception {
    String text = "Test";
    String patternString = "es";

    String quoted = Pattern.quote(patternString);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(quoted);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    assertTrue(matcher.matches());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters `es`, **literally**, do not match the `String` value `test`. They do however appear in the `String`. You can use `matcher#find()` to check that.